# Displaying an image to sending email in django

Tags: html, django, email

I would like to send an email containing the HTML email sent goes well with text by cons if my HTML content contains an image and it is not displayed.
Besides if I try to view the HTML template in the local picture is displayed correctly.
How to display the image in the HTML content?

**HTML Content**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: gray;
            color: red;
        }
        div, #globale{
            background-color:#eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <!--<img src=" {% static "Kamal.png" %}" alt="image"/>-->
        <!-<img src="{% static "Kamal.png" %}" alt="image"/>-->
        <div id="globale">
            <p>
                Convert the filename, content, mimetype triple into a MIME attachment
                object. Adjust headers to use Content-ID where applicable.
                Taken from <img src="Kamal.png" alt=" Mon Image "/>
                HTML is the method of choice for those wishing to send emails with rich
                text, layout and graphics. Often it is desirable to embed the graphics
                within the message so recipients can display the message directly,
                without further downloads.
                <img src="{% static "Kamal.png" %}" alt=" Mon Image "/>
                Some mail agents don't support HTML or their users prefer to receive
                plain text messages. Senders of HTML messages should include a plain
                text message as an alternate for these users.
                <img src="Kamal.png" />
                This recipe sends a short HTML message with a single embedded image
                and an alternate plain text message.
            </p>
            <h3>Message Reussi avec Image</h3>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you have in your `STATIC_URL` variable?

Comment: In my STATIC_URL variable i have this STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it won't work in localhost... The image won't be attached to the email -- what actually is gonna happen is the html in the email refer to the image in your server, e.g. (http://example.com/static/Kamal.png)

That been said, you can either set a full path `STATIC_URL` like:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://example.com/static/'
```

Instead of just:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The other option is using the `get_host()` method to build your url, in case you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`:

```
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'Kamal.png' %}" alt=" Mon Image "/>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

Comment: Thank you for the reply but fortunately when I test it locally by
http://localhost:8000/static/Kamal.png image appears correctly
I will try to replace the variable STATIC_URL with 'http://localhost:8000/static/'

Comment: when I replace the STATIC variable display URL does not change

Answer (score 0):

Send Domain Name Before Sending mail:

```
site=Site.objects.filter(id=1)
domain = site[0].domain //You will get your domain name 'xyz.com'
subject ="Conform your email address "
message = render_to_string('EmailTemplates/Email_verification.html', {
                    'email':user.email,
                    'user_display':user.first_name,
                    'domain':"{0}".format(domain),//It will return
                                    your doman 'http://127.0.0.1:8000 or etc'
                     })
                send_email(subject, message, user
)
```

Your Templates use Domain before static url:

```
<img src="{{domain}}/static/DataSearch/images/slider-image.png" alt="Party Wumpus" title="None" width="500" style="height: auto;">
```